# DOM loads, and then rest of the page

Tags: apache, load

I'm working on speeding up a website, when I do a load time test, there are 2 files needs to be loaded. The problem is the browser tries to load the index.php (html) first and when it's done loading that page, then it loads css, js & images... that makes the load time much longer. http://goo.gl/Af66y

Anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can include your css, js and images in `index` file. Put your css in `<style>` tag, js files in `<script>` and images you can convert to `base64` and assign to `img.src` or insert into `background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAErkJggg==")`

Comment: Well I don't want to inline them because the CSS contains lot of code.  Why my server serves the page like that? because I uploaded the same onto another server and there everything loads at the same time.